# c++ - use pointers, print the address instead of the value, why? (use operator)

Tags: c++

I wrote the vector class but when I print the object in my main it prints me the addresses of values, why?
Thank you very much for your help.

Vector.header:

```
#include <iostream>
class Vector{
private: 
int* first;
int* second;

public: 

Vector();
Vector(int num1, int num2);
~Vector();
Vector(Vector& other);
int* getFirst();
void setFirst(int* first);
int* getSecond();
void setSecond(int* second);
void print();

const Vector& operator=(const Vector& other){
    first = other.first;
    second = other.second;
    return *this;
}

Vector operator++(){
    return Vector(*first + 1, *second + 1);
}

Vector operator--(){
    return Vector(*first - 1, *second - 1);
}
};

Vector::Vector(){
first = 0;
second = 0;
}

Vector::Vector(int num1, int num2){
first = &num1;
second = &num2;
}

Vector::~Vector(){

}

Vector::Vector(Vector& other) : first(other.first), second(other.second){}

int* Vector::getFirst(){
return first;
}

void Vector::setFirst(int* f){
first = f;
}

int* Vector::getSecond(){
return second;
}

void Vector::setSecond(int* s){
second = s;
}

void Vector::print(){
std::cout << "<" << getFirst() << "," << getSecond() << ">" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"
int main(){
Vector* v1 = new Vector(2, 3);
Vector* v2 = new Vector(5, 6);

v1++;
v2--;

v1->print();
v2->print();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

print me:

```
<FDFDFDFD,ABABABAB>

<0000008F,FDFDFDFD>
```

Thank's for your help........

Comment: What do you expect when printing a pointer value? Did you mean to dereference them using `*`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your constructor `Vector(int num1, int num2)` is storing the address of temporary variables that go out of scope when the constructor exits. Dereferencing `first` or `second` will be UB. You can't do `first = &num1;` or `second = &num2;` in your constructor.

Comment: Why are `first` and `second` pointers to integers anyways? Make them integers and this problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

> I print the object in my main it prints me the addresses of values, why?

Because the type of each expression is pointer. And stream insertion operator is specified to output the address with a pointer operand (unless it is a pointer to a character).

Note that the behaviour of the program is undefined, because you call a member functions on pointers that points to arbitrary addresses:

> ```
> Vector* v1 = new Vector(2, 3);
> ```

At this moment `v1` points to a valid object.

> ```
> v1++;
> ```

Now `v1` no longer points to a valid object.

> ```
> v1->print();
> ```

The behaviour is undefined.